discord.js MessageTyping errer
I was making a discord bot with discord.js, but when I use MessageTyping Intent, I get an error.
Errer:
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:174



throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);



л



RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.



at Function.resolve.(/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:17 4:11)



at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:168:35 at Array.map (<anonymous>)



at Function.resolve (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:16 8:18



at new BitField (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:33:38) at new IntentsBitField (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/IntentsBitF ield.js:9:1)



at Client._validateOptions (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Clien t.js:531:25)



at new Client (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:80:10) at file:///home/container/index.js:17:16.



at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:234:25) { code: 'BitFieldInvalid'



}

Part of the code where the intent is used.
Code:
    if (message.content.startsWith('!핑')) {

        try {

            // 응답속도 계산

            const start = Date.now();

            const msg = await message.channel.send('Pong!');

            const ping = Date.now() - start;



            // 응답속도 임베드

            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()

                .setTitle(' 퐁!')

                .setDescription(`현재 봇의 응답속도(ms)는 ${ping} 입니다.`)

                .setColor('#FFFF00')

                .setTimestamp();



            await msg.edit({ content: '', embeds: [embed] });



            // 유저가 입력 중일 때

            const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content;

            const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 3000 });



            collector.on('collect', async () => {

                await msg.channel.send('.....그런데 봇은 왜 핑 퐁이 기본이라는 걸까요...?');

                collector.stop(); // 메시지 수집기 중지

            });



            collector.on('end', () => {

                if (collector.collected.size === 0) {

                    msg.channel.send('.....그런데 봇은 왜 핑 퐁이 기본이라는 걸까요...?');

                }

            });



        } catch (error) {

            console.error('!핑 명령어 처리 중 오류 발생:', error);

        }

    }

});

This is the code between import and gatewayintentbits.
Code:
import 'dotenv/config';

import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType, EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';

import axios from 'axios';

import fs from 'fs';

import sharp from 'sharp';

import { PNG } from 'pngjs';

import cron from 'node-cron';



// Import pixelmatch dynamically at the start

let pixelmatch;

(async () => {

    pixelmatch = (await import('pixelmatch')).default;

})();



const DISCORD_TOKEN = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;



const client = new Client({

    intents: [

        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,

        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,

        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,

        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,

        GatewayIntentBits.MessageTyping, // 채팅 입력 감지

    ],

});

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what is causing this error and how to fix it.
I'd also like an alternative approach that doesn't use this intent.
(This question was written using a machine translation (from Korean to English). The translation may be strange.)
I haven't tried anything else since I started this.

whate version of discord.js are you using??

not MessageTyping, but GuildMessageTyping (and DirectMessageTyping if you need DM typing.)
const client = new Client({

    intents: [

        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,

        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,

        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,

        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,

        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping, // 채팅 입력 감지

    ],

});

